# What is this button on my MacBook Pro Touch Bar?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-bar

[image: What is this button?]

I've highlighted it in red in the screenshot.  It seems to show up almost all the time on my Mac, regardless of what applications I have open.  Pressing it does nothing apparent.  If I "Customize Control Strip..." in System Preferences, it disappears.  It does not appear on [Apple's list of touch bar icons](https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/touch-bar/touch-bar-icons-and-images/).

I'm running macOS 10.12.6 on a 13" MBP.

Comment: It looks like something to do with the trackpad. Do you have any third-party trackpad software installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like it is from BetterTouchTool. You can configure it in the settings for BTT:

https://github.com/fifafu/BetterTouchTool/issues/1033

> **fifafu:** You can disable it in the Touch Bar settings in BTT (go to the Touch Bar tab, then click the "General Touch Bar settings" button.
>   This may require a restart of BTT to become effective.